# json_encode for flot chart

Tags: php, json, flot

I am stumped on producing a specifically formatted JSON for a flot chart.  Any help is much appreciated!

I use this php code

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM all_programs_extended');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$newData[] = array(
                    'label' => $row['program_type'],
                    'data'  => array(
                "employee1" => $row['employee1'],
                                "employee2" => $row['employee2'],
                "employee3" => $row['employee3']                        
                                )
                    );

}


print json_encode($newData);
```

which produces this valid JSON

```
[{"label":"Program A","data":{"employee1":"5","employee2":"3","employee3":"1"}},
{"label":"Program B","data":{"employee1":"0","employee2":"4","employee3":"2"}},
{"label":"Program A","data":{"employee1":"4","employee2":"2","employee3":"4"}}]
```

but I need it look like this:

```
{
    "label": "Program A",
    "data": [[employee1, 5], [employee2, 3], [employee3, 1]],   
     "label": "Program B",
    "data": [[employee1, 0], [employee2, 4], [employee3, 2]],
     "label": "Program C",
    "data": [[employee1, 4], [employee2, 2], [employee3, 4]]

}
```

I seem to have mixed up by brackets and braces, and I also need a comma separating my value pairs between brackets rather than the colon in the first JSON.  Be nice to get ride of the quotation marks around the numbers too!

Thanks very much!

Comment: There can't be **same** keys in json on the same level. JSON you want is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Just suround `employeeX` by an additional array:

```
$newData[] = array(
    'label' => $row['program_type'],
    'data'  => array(
        array(
            "employee1" => $row['employee1']
        ),
        array (
            "employee2" => $row['employee2']
        ),
        array (
            "employee3" => $row['employee3']
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That does produce a nested array, but the flot chart is finicky - it really wants the inner arrays to have brackets around the value pairs not curly braces, for example: [employee1, 5] and no semi-colon but rather a comma separating the values - is that something I need to do in php after I render the json object through json_encode?